# Live Microphone Playback in Windows 7

Tags: microphone, playback

I've just upgraded to Windows 7 on my Dell Latitude E5500.

I have installed all the default drivers but how can I configure the laptop to enable live microphone playback? I managed to do this in XP by changing some registry values through SigmaTel audio, but this driver doesn't appear to be present in Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the volume icon and select recording devices. Select your microphone and there should be a tab called "Listen."  Select your playback device (speakers) and you now have cheap monitor speakers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there is no "Listen" tab. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: There totally a listen tab in in Win7 if you doubleclick your microphone in that list.. are you sure you selected a microphone?